# How can I get combined parameter from multiple function calling

Tags: javascript

I'd like to know how to get parameter with call it multiple and then I'd like to get the results that is combined

I tried to do it with small example but I can't get the exact results.

this is the small example :

```js
 const getXY = (x, y) => {
    let result = { x: x, y: y };
    console.log(result);
  };
  getXY("x is first");
  getXY("y is second");
```

### result:

```
{x: "x is first", y: undefined}
{x: "y is second", y: undefined}
```

### What I want it to be :

```
{x:"x is first", y:"y is second"}
```

what I mean is when u call the function two times or three times with one parameter, and the parameter is going to be combined
Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer: you can't.

Not without saving to an array or something or changing the block to append to the object, etc., etc. Pass it as two parameters instead of one parameter twice.

```js
const getXY = (x, y) => {
  let result = { x: x, y: y };
  console.log(result);
};
getXY("x is first", "y is second");
```

Here's an example of a way to do it with multiple calls.

```js
var obj;
const getXY = (x) => {
  if(obj != undefined)
  {
    obj.y = x;
    console.log(obj);
  }
  else
    obj = {x: x};
};
getXY("x is first");
getXY("y is second");
```

Comment: I have two `select` tag in my project so i need to call it twice , is it impossible??

Comment: Thank you so much ! would u tell me how i can get similar results?

Comment: In this way, yeah it's not possible. You'd need some extra logic in there to store whether or not it writes it to x or y and then you'd also need a stored reference to the returned object which could then be manipulated again later.

Comment: does it call optional function??

Comment: Thank you so much ! I used the currying function instead earlier, Would I achieve that results with currying??

Comment: I included an example in my answer. You could use currying, but that wouldn't necessarily solve your problem here as you'd still need to know whether or not to write to x or y.

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking cannot be achieved by just a function. I modified your function so it acts more like a class.

```js
 const getXY = (param) => {
    if (this.x) {
      this.y = param;
    } else {
      this.x = param;
    }

    let result = { x: this.x, y: this.y };
    console.log(result);
  };
  getXY("x is first");
  getXY("y is second");
```